# Publishing program through active directory

Tags: windows, active-directory, dns, windows-installer

I have published two programs to users through active directory. This first allows non-administrative users to install with no problems. The second, Flash Player's latest version, fails for non-administrators.

The user exists in the OU and the group policy is enabled. The .MSI file rests on a shared network drive that everyone has access to.

Is there another location to set permissions for published msi installers?

Answer (score 0):

MSI packages don't use permissions for the installation process. It all depends on their configuration.

It seems that the Flash Player MSI uses a per-machine installation, so non-Administrators cannot install it. Also, this cannot be changed without converting normal user accounts into Administrators.

A solution is to deploy it only to Administrator users.

Comment: The msi is provided on adobe's website. I'm wondering if publishing the msi through active directory automatically gives any assigned user the rights to install the program.